# How to fix my wrong image loading in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a little game project with friends using python and pygame.

Today I tried to write the weapon part in the code and everything is correct but when I'm  running the code, it is loading the wrong weapons images (it is loading the character images which are in another folder...) so I checked the code many times but I dont find anything and why is it taking the character images...

(Btw we didnt designed the weapons already, I just wanted to finish the code part so that we can work on weapons design later... so I just replaced them with temporary images with number for animation)

Here is the part of the code loading the weapon images, I've done almost the same thing for the character images and its working perfectly:

```
weapon_animation_types = ["empty", "sword", "rifle"]
for weapon_animation in weapon_animation_types:
    weapon_temp_list = []
    longueur_fichier_weapon = len(os.listdir(f'img/weapons/{weapon_animation}'))
    for j in range(longueur_fichier_weapon):
        img_weapon = pygame.image.load(f'img/weapons/{weapon_animation}/{j}.png')
        img_weapon = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))
        weapon_temp_list.append(img_weapon)
    self.weapons_animations_list.append(temp_list)
self.weapon_image = self.weapons_animations_list[self.weapon][self.weapon_frame_index]
```

I dont think the issue is in this part but we never know...

Here you can find the GitHub repository (which I think is more usefull to understand my issue...) of the project with the full code and the images to be loaded:
https://github.com/Nirs123/Neon_City_Brawl

Appreciate every feedback :)

Comment: Is it maybe that you are doing `self.weapons_animations_list.append(temp_list)` instead of `self.weapons_animations_list.append(weapon_temp_list)`?

Comment: I just changed that and it's true that it could be the solution but it didn't change the images loaded :/ (you can check changes in GitHub repository if you want)

Comment: Please don't let people read through an entire repository. Instead, create a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Its just that you need the images in the repository to understand: running the code makes you understand easier because its pretty hard to explain my issue with words (especially because I'm french...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img_weapon = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))`

Should be

`img_weapon = pygame.transform.scale(img_weapon, (int(img_weapon.get_width() * scale), int(img_weapon.get_height() * scale)))`

You're re-assigning `img_weapon` with a scaled version of another surface, named `img`.